# Issue in Parsing XML in Visual C++

Tags: c++, xml, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am trying to parse the xml but when I import msxml2.dll in visual studio 2013 and getting the error cannot open msxml2.tlh.

can anyone please help me out of this.

Or

Can anyone please tell me any other way to parse the XML in visual c++ win32 project?

Comment: Is that tlb file's name is same as the .dll file name? How I link  it?

Comment: I think you don't have to import that kind of standard DLL. The msxml2.h file is shipped with the SDK.